# How to use fgets when you need to break from blanks

Tags: c, fgets

I need to seperate some sentences. For example, the txt file is something like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec commodo metus sit amet mauris facilisis, fringilla convallis erat dictum. 


Quisque scelerisque turpis hendrerit, sodales erat et, convallis nisl. 
Etiam ultrices vulputate purus, id tincidunt purus semper vel.
```

There are many blocks (as blocks, I mean two sentences in a row) so I can not manually seperate them. I need to seperate them by blanks between them. However, fgets works line by line so it would give me;

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Donec commodo metus sit amet mauris facilisis, fringilla convallis erat dictum. 

Quisque scelerisque turpis hendrerit, sodales erat et, convallis nisl. 

Etiam ultrices vulputate purus, id tincidunt purus semper vel.
```

What should I do? I think about, yet no starting point. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Since many people did not understand that, I see I was unclear. So the point is that, from txt file above, I need to separate those sentences by blanks and add those sentences to an array (array of strings in this case).

So, when this process is done, arrayofstrings[0] must give us

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec commodo metus sit amet mauris facilisis, fringilla convallis erat dictum.
```

Then next index should be similar to this. One of the problems is that I can not be sure that those multi-sentences in indexes are not always constructed by two sentences. I mean, for an index i, arrayofstrings[i] can be as:

```
Ut mattis mi ac purus tempor bibendum. 
Praesent sed metus enim. 
Pellentesque at orci id mauris consectetur consequat.
```

So process can not be done depending on the two-line idea.

Comment: Read with `fgets`. If you read an empty line, skip it and create a new "block"; Otherwise append to the current "block".

Comment: Actually I don't get it fully but I will try to implement that.

Comment: First idea that comes to my mind is that, collect chars in an array until you see a blank. Then those array is a string now due to rules of C. Then for every string -also you can say array- add it to the general array. Then you can use the general array to reach the strings.

Comment: Does your input file have the blank lines shown separating the blocks?  If so, the problem is trivial — you can spot when `fgets()` returns a line consisting of only a newline.  If the input is actually a continuous set of lines, one sentence per line, with no blank lines, then you simply need to read two lines (into two separate buffers) and then process the two lines in the block, separating them in the output.  That's also not very difficult — the main issue is what to do if the file contains an odd number of lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In the file, those two consecutive sentences are related actually. So there won't be odd number of lines. Since it is job related, I could not share it due to confidental information.

Comment: Having to keep corporate information secret is fine.  You just need to show equivalent data.  You've not said whether the blank lines exist in the input data. It would be a good idea if you showed the code you've written so far and explain what the problem is when you run that code on the data shown in the question.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: Alright, thank you for correction and help. I will try to do better.

Comment: At a guess, you want to split the line into words? After `fgets`, you may want to loop on `strtok`. If you're trying to save all the words in the _file_ in a big array you may also need `strdup`

Comment: I tried to explain further.

Comment: Do the lines require further processing, such as with entries in a database, or are they just strings?

Comment: Only strings, yolo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your read to capture each continual block of text (including the embedded `'\n'`) characters can be done in a number of ways, but one of the simplest approaches is keep a simple flag that tracts the state of whether you are in between paragraphs reading whitespace, or in a block reading text. (the flag is a simple state-variable)

Then it's just a matter of reading each line and, if it's part of a block, appending each line in the block to a single index in your array, or if it's a blank line, advance to the next index and reset your variables to prepare for reading the next block. If using a fixed-size array, don't forget to protect your array bounds by checking each new line appended at an index will fit. A rough outline would be:

- (for fixed array of strings) declare an array of rows and columns with the columns sufficient to hold each block of text.
- start with your read-state variable set to `0` (false) indicating you are before or between lines of text.
- while your array isn't full, read each line.
- if the line contains only a `'\n'` character,

  - check your flag to determine if you were reading text before this line, if so you are done filling the array index,

    - advance the index to next,
  - reset your flag `0`, and
  - reset number of chars used at index to `0`.
- the only other alternative (the `else`) part is that you read a line containing text that is part of a block. Here you would:

  - compute the total number of bytes needed by what is currently stored at the index, plus the length of the new line (plus `1` for the nul-terminating character).
  - if line with fit in index,

    - append current line to index
    - update total characters stored in index
  - otherwise (`else`) line won't fit in index, handle the error
- set in block flag to `1` (true)

Now obviously rather than using a fixed array, you can either use an array of pointers and allocate storage for each index as needed, or you can use a pointer-to-pointer and allocate both pointers-as-needed and storage for each line. Up to you.

Turning the outline into a short example that uses the `inblk` variables as your flag to determine if you are in a block reading lines, or before or between blocks, and using the `offset` in each index to track the current number of characters used to protect the fixed array bounds, you could do:

(updated to handle final block issue pointed out by [@AndreasWenzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12149471/andreas-wenzel), and a few type clean-ups added)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NROWS  128    /* max number of rows (sentences) in array */
#define MAXCHR 256    /* max number of chars in read-buffer */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
  char buf[MAXCHR] = "",              /* buffer to hold each line */
       array[NROWS][MAXCHR] = {""};   /* array of strings */
  int  inblk = 0,                     /* flag - in block reading text */
       ndx = 0;                       /* array index */
  size_t offset = 0;                  /* offset in index to write string */
  /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
  FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

  if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
      perror ("file open failed");
      return 1;
  }
  
  /* while array not full, read line into buf */
  while (ndx < NROWS && fgets (buf, MAXCHR, fp)) {
    if (*buf == '\n') {               /* 1st char is \n ? */
      if (inblk) {                    /* if in block ? */
        ndx += 1;                     /* end of block, advance index */
      }
      inblk = 0;                      /* reset flag 0 (false) */
      offset = 0;                     /* reset offset */
    }
    else {  /* otherwise reading line in block */
      size_t buflen = strlen (buf),           /* length of string in buf */
             reqd = offset + buflen + 1;      /* get total required chars */
      if (reqd < MAXCHR) {                    /* line will fit in array */
        strcpy (array[ndx] + offset, buf);    /* append buf to index */
        offset += buflen;                     /* update offset to end */
      }
      else {  /* line won't fit in remaining space, handle error */
        fputs ("error: line exceeds storage for array.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
      }
      inblk = 1;                      /* set in block flag 1 (true) */
    }
  }
  if (inblk) {    /* close and write final block */
    ndx += 1;     /* end of block, advance index */
  }
  
  if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
      fclose (fp);

  for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {     /* output reults */
    printf ("array[%2d]:\n%s\n", i, array[i]);
  }
}
```

**Example Input File**

Given your description of an inconsistent number of lines per-block and potentially inconsistent number of empty lines between the blocks, the following was used:

```
$ cat dat/blks.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec commodo metus sit amet mauris facilisis, fringilla convallis erat dictum.


Quisque scelerisque turpis hendrerit, sodales erat et, convallis nisl.
Etiam ultrices vulputate purus, id tincidunt purus semper vel.

Ut mattis mi ac purus tempor bibendum.
Praesent sed metus enim.
Pellentesque at orci id mauris consectetur consequat.
```

**Example Use/Output**

Providing the filename to read as the first argument to the program (or redirecting the file on `stdin` to the program) would result in the following:

```
$ ./bin/combineblks dat/blks.txt
array[ 0]:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec commodo metus sit amet mauris facilisis, fringilla convallis erat dictum.

array[ 1]:
Quisque scelerisque turpis hendrerit, sodales erat et, convallis nisl.
Etiam ultrices vulputate purus, id tincidunt purus semper vel.

array[ 2]:
Ut mattis mi ac purus tempor bibendum.
Praesent sed metus enim.
Pellentesque at orci id mauris consectetur consequat.
```

Where each array index holds a complete block of text from the file, including the embedded and trailing `\n'` characters.

Comment: Thank you. It does not work with copy paste, needs some correction but the aim of here is not copy-pasting at all. So it is good. However, one question. Is it in C?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, handling of non-POSIX newlines was omitted. I see you incorporated it, Job will done, thanks for pointing that out and I'll drop an update.

Comment: Thank you. Updated to handle final block regardless of number of final blank lines.

Comment: @ihatec - see updated answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes, I can confirm that it works now. Unfortunately, I can't give you more than one upvote. :-(

Comment: @AndreasWenzel - I'm in the same spot with your answer....

Comment: @ihatec: The program is written in C and the current and previous version should compile using copy&paste. At least it does with me. The previous version had a runtime issue (but compiled fine), which has been fixed now.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- good eyes. Again.... (it sure was a long way back to the bucket....)

Comment: I was sick for a couple days. Just can be here now. Thank you guys! For both solution and willing to help!

Comment: @ihatec Good lock with your coding. C is a fantastic language to learn that will make you a better programmer regardless of what language you end up writing it. Learning C isn't a race, it takes time, the details matter. Best approach is to just enjoy the journey,like chess, it's something you can improve on for a lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this using the following algorithm:

I create an array `char *strings[MAX_STRINGS]`, in which every pointer is initialized to zero to indicate whether it points to a valid string or not. I read one line at a time using `fgets` and append that line to the current string. I use dynamic memory allocation (i.e. `malloc`) to store and grow the actual strings, but the array `strings` itself is fixed-length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRINGS 200
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 300

int main( void )
{
    char *strings[MAX_STRINGS] = { NULL };
    int num_strings = 0;

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    //read one line of input per loop iteration
    while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        //make sure that line was not too long for input buffer
        if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL )
        {
            size_t len;

            //a missing newline character is not wrong
            //if end-of-file has been reached
            if ( !feof(stdin) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Line too long for input buffer!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //newline character is missing at end-of-file, so add it
            len = strlen( line );
            if ( len + 1 == sizeof line )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "No room for adding newline character!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            line[len]   = '\n';
            line[len+1] = '\0';
        }

        //determine whether line is empty
        if ( line[0] == '\n' )
        {
            //determine whether current string already has content
            if ( strings[num_strings] != NULL )
            {
                num_strings++;
            }

            //skip to next line
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that maximum number of strings has not been exceeded
        if ( num_strings == MAX_STRINGS )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Maximum number of strings exceeded!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //determine whether current string already exists
        if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
        {
            //allocate memory for new string
            strings[num_strings] = malloc( strlen(line) + 1 );
            if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //copy string to allocated memory
            strcpy( strings[num_strings], line );
        }
        else
        {
            size_t len;

            //resize memory buffer for adding new string
            len = strlen( strings[num_strings] );
            len += strlen(line) + 1;
            strings[num_strings] = realloc( strings[num_strings], len );
            if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //concatenate the current line with the existing string
            strcat( strings[num_strings], line );
        }
    }

    //mark last string as complete, if it exists
    if ( strings[num_strings] != NULL )
    {
        num_strings++;
    }

    //print results

    printf( "Found a total of %d strings.\n\n", num_strings );

    for ( int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++ )
    {
        printf( "strings[%d] has the following content:\n%s\n", i, strings[i] );

        //perform cleanup
        free( strings[i] );
    }
}
```

For the input posted in the question, this program has the following output:

```
Found a total of 2 strings.

strings[0] has the following content:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec commodo metus sit amet mauris facilisis, fringilla convallis erat dictum. 

strings[1] has the following content:
Quisque scelerisque turpis hendrerit, sodales erat et, convallis nisl. 
Etiam ultrices vulputate purus, id tincidunt purus semper vel.
```

However, the code above is not optimized very well, because:

1. It does not remember the length of the string, but instead repeatedly uses `strcat` and `strlen` to determine the length of the string over and over again. This is highly inefficient, if the string gets very large.
2. It calls `realloc` every time it adds a new string. This could cause the entire string to be copied to a new memory buffer every time, which would be highly inefficient, if the string gets very large.

Another issue is that

```
#define MAX_STRINGS 200
```

will create a hard-limit on the number of strings that this program can handle. Although this number can be increased if necessary, it would probably be better to do this automatically.

Therefore, instead of defining `strings` like this

```
char *strings[MAX_STRINGS] = { NULL };
```

it would probably be better to define it like this

```
char **strings;
```

and to use dynamic memory allocation to allocate memory for the string pointers, and to grow the memory as necessary.

Here is another solution which is more complex, but fixes these issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 300

int main( void )
{
    char **strings;
    size_t num_strings = 0; //number of valid strings
    size_t cap_strings = 100; //current capacity of strings

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    size_t current_string_length = 0;
    size_t current_string_capacity = 0;

    //allocate initial memory for array "strings"
    strings = malloc( cap_strings * sizeof *strings );
    if ( strings == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //read one line of input per loop iteration
    while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        size_t len;

        //make sure that line was not too long for input buffer
        len = strlen( line );
        if ( len == 0 || line[len-1] != '\n' )
        {
            //a missing newline character is not wrong
            //if end-of-file has been reached
            if ( !feof(stdin) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Line too long for input buffer!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //newline character is missing at end-of-file, so add it
            if ( len + 1 == sizeof line )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "No room for adding newline character!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            line[len]   = '\n';
            line[len+1] = '\0';
            len++;
        }

        //determine whether line is empty
        if ( line[0] == '\n' )
        {
            //determine whether current string already has content
            if ( current_string_length > 0 )
            {
                //shrink allocated memory to required size
                strings[num_strings] = realloc( strings[num_strings], current_string_length + 1  );
                if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
                {
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                //mark string as complete
                num_strings++;
                current_string_length = 0;
            }

            //skip to next line
            continue;
        }

        //grow array "strings" if necessary
        if ( num_strings == cap_strings )
        {
            cap_strings *= 2;
            strings = realloc( strings, cap_strings * sizeof *strings );
            if ( strings == NULL )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }

        //determine whether current string already exists
        if ( current_string_length == 0 )
        {
            //allocate memory for new string
            current_string_capacity = 200;
            if ( current_string_capacity < len + 1 )
                current_string_capacity = len + 1;
            strings[num_strings] = malloc( current_string_capacity );
            if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //copy string to allocated memory
            strcpy( strings[num_strings], line );

            //update length of current string
            current_string_length = len;
        }
        else
        {
            //remember previous length of string
            size_t prev_string_length = current_string_length;

            //resize memory buffer, if necessary
            current_string_length += len;
            if ( current_string_capacity < len + 1 )
            {
                current_string_capacity *= 2;
                if ( current_string_capacity < len + 1 )
                    current_string_capacity = len + 1;
                strings[num_strings] = realloc( strings[num_strings], current_string_capacity );
                if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
            }

            //add the current line to the existing string
            strcpy( strings[num_strings]+prev_string_length, line );
        }
    }

    //shrink last string and mark as complete, if it exists
    if ( current_string_length != 0 )
    {
        //shrink allocated memory to required size
        strings[num_strings] = realloc( strings[num_strings], current_string_length + 1  );
        if ( strings[num_strings] == NULL )
        {
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        num_strings++;
    }

    //print results

    printf( "Found a total of %zu strings.\n\n", num_strings );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num_strings; i++ )
    {
        printf( "strings[%zu] has the following content:\n%s\n", i, strings[i] );

        //perform cleanup
        free( strings[i] );
    }

    //more cleanup
    free( strings );
}
```

Comment: My bad then, my old eyes skipped over it.

Comment: Andrew,  Code for `newline character is missing at end-of-file, so add it` is interesting. Sounds like a good idea to "repair" files, yet could also be view as bad to add data not present in original file. C lib has "Whether the last line requires a
terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.", so by adding one this code may be going for or against the implementation.

Comment: `if ( strcmp( line, "\n" ) == 0 )` looks heavy when only `if (line[0] == '\n' )` needed.   I doubt a compiler would make that optimization.

Comment: `strcat( strings[num_strings], line );`  --> Avoid a O(n*n) [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).  Consider keeping a running length: `strcpy( strings[num_strings] + length_of_strings_num_strings, line );`

Comment: @chux: When printing the lines, my program is assuming that all lines are stored with a `\n` newline character at the end. Therefore, it seems appropriate to add a newline character if it is missing in the input. An common alternative would be to remove all newline characters from the input, if they exist. However I need some delimiter for storing the individual lines in the strings, so it seems appropriate to keep the newline characters, and to add them if necessary.

Comment: @chux: You are right that my initial code does not scale well, due to my code using a Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm. I deliberately did not fix this in my initial code, because it would have made the code more complex, and I did not want to make the code too hard for OP to understand. However, I have now added a second more efficient solution to my answer, which remembers the length of the current string, as you suggested.

Comment: @chux: However, I am not sure if I have actually removed the Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm completely from my program, as my use of `realloc` is probably not optimal. In the worst-case, `realloc` will copy the entire string, whenever memory for growing the string is needed. It would probably be better to double the size of the memory buffer every time, and then to shrink it after the final size is known.

Comment: @chux: I believe I have now also resolved the issue of `realloc` in the second program of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<sup><sub>Oooh, oooh, me too!</sub></sup>
Another option is to simply read the file *en bloc* and then tokenize on sequences of two or more newlines.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


char * file_to_string( const char * filename, const char * mode )  // NULL, "", "text", "r" --> text mode
{                                                                  // "b", "binary", "rb" --> binary mode
    struct stat st;
    size_t size  = stat( filename, &st ) ? 0 : st.st_size;
    char * s     = calloc( size + 1, 1 );
    FILE * f     = fopen( filename, (mode and ((*mode == 'b') or (mode[1] == 'b'))) ? "rb" : "r" );
    bool   ok    = size and s and f;
    if (ok) fread( s, 1, size, f );
    if (f) fclose( f );
    if (ok) return s;
    free( s );
    return NULL;
}


char * skip_whitespace( char ** s )
{
    while (isspace( **s )) ++(*s);
    return *s;
}


char * find_end_of_paragraph( char ** s )
{
    char  * p = strstr( *s, "\n\n" );           // a paragraph ends with two (or more) newlines
    if (!p) p = strchr( *s, '\0' );             // or at the end of the string
    while ((*s < p) and isspace( p[-1] )) --p;  // (also trim trailing whitespace)
    return (*s = p);
}


size_t sp_loop( char * s, char ** ss )  // worker function for split_paragraphs()
{                                       // loops through the "paragraphs" in the argument string
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*skip_whitespace( &s ))
    {
        count += 1;
        if (ss) *ss++ = s;
        if (*find_end_of_paragraph( &s ) and ss) *s++ = '\0';
    }
    return count;
}

char ** split_paragraphs( char * s )  // returns a NULL-terminated array referencing
{                                     // paragraphs in the modified argument string
    size_t count = sp_loop( s, NULL );
    char ** ss = calloc( sizeof(char *), count + 1 );  // (returns NULL on alloc failure)
    if (ss) sp_loop( s, ss );
    return ss;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )  // main takes FILENAME as argument
{
    if (argc != 2) return 0;
    
    char * s = file_to_string( argv[1], "text" );
    if (s)
    {
        char ** paragraphs = split_paragraphs( s );
        if (paragraphs)
        {
            if (!*paragraphs)
            {
                puts( "\n(empty file: no paragraphs)" );
            }
            else 
            {
                size_t n = 0;
                while (paragraphs[n]) printf( "\n'''%s'''\n", paragraphs[n++] );
                printf( "\n(%zu paragraph%s)\n", n, n == 1 ? "" : "s" );
            }
            free( paragraphs );
        }
        free( s );
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This does mean that you cannot *modify* paragraph's without also modifying the sourced string, but that may be all you need.

It is a two-pass tokenization. Plus the read means three passes total, plus the allocations.

The paragraph tokenizer strips both leading and trailing whitespace from the tokenized strings, and works properly for files with both leading and trailing sequences of two or more newlines.